# Customize "want contacts" prompt?

Tags: ios, ios6, abaddressbook

Is there a way to customize the prompt that appears when my app tries to access the address book?

I want to add an explanation of what data I use, and why I need it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In iOS 6, this has been added to the `Info.plist` file. You want to set the key `NSContactsUsageDescription` (remember that you can [localize this in `InfoPlist.strings`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-102276)). The descriptive name for this is "Privacy - Contacts Usage Description."

I'm not aware of a way to set this in iOS 5.

Comment: I think this warning is new in iOS 6, so your answer is complete. (And also exactly what I was hoping for; I read this months ago, but couldn't find it again!)